# Prove the image of a polynomial map is an algebraic variety.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to learn about polynomial morphisms between algebraic varieties and i have come across an example:

$$ \phi: \quad \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^2$$
Given by: $$ \phi(t) = (t^2,t^3)$$
Has image $$ im(\phi) = V(y^2-x^3) \subset \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^2$$
I was wondering how do you show such a thing?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: you're trying to show that $k[x,y]\to k[t]$ given by $x\mapsto t^2$ and $y\mapsto t^3$ has kernel $y^2-x^3$. Let $I$ denote this kernel. Then, evidently one has that $(y^2-x^3)\subseteq I$. But, note that $I$ is prime, and since it contains the prime $(y^2-x^3$) if it were any larger it would have to be maximal. Show that the image (of the ring map) is not a field.

Geometrically you're showing that $\text{im}(\phi)$ is irreducible is contained this dimension $1$ thing $V(y^2-x^3)$, but is not a point, so is actually all of $V(y^2-x^3)$.

Comment: Very nice answer, +1. The image of the ring map is not only not a field, it is not even a UFD! Indeed, the image is the subring of $k[t]$ generated by $t^{2}, t^{3}$, and one can show that both $t^{2}$ and $t^{3}$ are irreducible elements of this subring, whence $t^{6} = t^{3} \cdot t^{3} = t^{2} \cdot t^{2} \cdot t^{2}$ has two distinct factorizations into irreducibles. (But of course, this is unnecessary for the great solution above.)

Comment: @AlexWertheim Thanks. :) In fact, as you probably know, this is the normalization map.

Answer (score 0):

The map $$(x,y)\mapsto \frac{y}{x}$$ is an inverse.

Comment: What does that mean? It's certainly not an inverse map of rings/schemes? The scheme-theoretic image is non-normal. What you've described is, essentially, the isomorphism on normalizations.

Comment: Well you can take it any way you want. It is the kernel of a proof. In any case it is a rational map from the curve to the line proving they are birational. I suspect OP, does not know scheme theory yet.

Comment: Yes, but then you might confuse them because you aren't explaining what happens to $(0,0)$.

Comment: Like I said you can use it to establish that the map is bijective, which I think was OP real question. Its clear what happens at zero. As for general theory rational maps are not everywhere defined, is not regular at $(0,0)$.